# Reading JSON objects/arrays within a C# Controller

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Firstly, I apologise in advance for any incorrect terminology!  I've gone snow blind reading so many blog posts and articles on how I might do this and have come to an impasse.

I've been successfully passing parameters via AJAX to an MVC action in a controller, which returns the SQL datatable in JSON format for me to consume in my page.  An example set of parameters I send looks like this;

```
var parameters = {
    pSQL: "SELECT * FROM v_MyTable",
    pSQLServer: "SERVER01",
};
```

My Client Side Script looks like this;

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ControllerName/GiveMeJSON',
    data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    ...
});
```

My Controller Action simply works like this;

```
    public string GiveMeJSON(string pSQL, string pSQLServer)
    {
        var SQL = pSQL
        var SQLSERVER = pSQLServer

        // do stuff and return JSON
    }
```

This has been working great for me. I send JSON request data as POST and receive JSON data in return. Brilliant.

Now, I'd like to extend the functionality of my action so that I can pass it an additional set of variables as an array, something like this;

```
var parameters = {
    pSQL: "SELECT * FROM v_MyTable",
    pSQLServer: "SERVER01",
    pMoreParams: {
        pParameter1: "ABC",
        pParameter2: "XYZ",
    }
};
```

...where the parameter names in MoreParams could be called anything, with any type of value. That's important, as I think that rules out using models?

This results in the POST request BODY looking like this Valid JSON;

```
{"pSQL":"SELECT * FROM v_MyTable","pSQLSERVER":"SERVER01","pMoreParams":{"pParameter1":"ABC","pParameter2":"XYZ"}}
```

So the data I need is clearly going to the server, but yet I am really struggling with enumerating/accessing those additional items in the pMoreParams array.  I seem to be getting close, I've played around with using...

```
public string GiveMeJSON(string pSQL, string pSQLServer, List<string> pMoreParams)
```

...and I've had a foreach loop in the controller run for however many items are in the pMoreParams list (2, in the above example) but just can't seem to work out how to access/read those values in that list in the controller action.

I'm at a loss now as to how to loop through and read the extra data I am sending. I sense I'm close, with using the `List<string>` or `IEnumerable` - but the solution evades me.

I have had more success getting the controller reading those extra parameters when I send them as a simple valid JSON string, like so;

```
var parameters = {
    pSQL: "SELECT * FROM v_MyTable",
    pSQLServer: "SERVER01",
    pMoreParams: '[{"name": "pParameter1", "value": "ABC" },{"name": "pParameter2", "value": "XYZ"}]'
};
```

...and using a controller actions which look something like this;

```
    public class SQLParam
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }


    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pMoreParams) == false)
    {
        var sqlparameters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SQLParam[]>(pMoreParams);
        foreach (var sqlparameter in sqlparameters)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(sqlparameter.name, sqlparameter.value);
        }
    };
```

...BUT I then lose the ability to easily read and modify those values in client-side jquery/javascript, and I'd MUCH prefer/desire to keep the way I define the parameters as it is, so that I can easily read and modify the values using a one-liner, something like;

```
parameters.pMoreParams[0].pParameter1 = "NEW VALUE";
```

...as I can then simply trigger the AJAX call again and it POSTS with the new parameter values.

Any help and advice is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to gain from allowing someone to access, any table on any server - via http? - I know what you are posting may not exactly be your code 1 - 1, but it is a major security concern, as pointed out by Andrés

Comment: The code above is over simplified - the pSQL parameter is the name of a predefined .sql file local to the server filesystem which the server reads in, adds any parameters supplied, executes and returns JSON. The pSQLServer param also isn't actually a server or connection string but a reference to a server side database value that contains a connection string created and accessible only by the app admin. I am very happy now that the app is becoming resistant to SQLInjection once I redo some of my earlier code to use parameterisation in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

When you send in:

```
"pMoreParams":{"pParameter1":"ABC","pParameter2":"XYZ"}
```

You are sending in an object called `pMoreParams` that has two properties.

If you want to get these from the controller, you would need to create a C# object which mirrors the JSON you are sending in.

```
public class MoreParams
{
    public string pParameter1 {get;set;}
    public string pParameter2 {get;set;}
}
```

And then update your action method:

```
public string GiveMeJSON(string pSQL, string pSQLServer, MoreParams pMoreParams)
{
    var param1 = pMoreParams.pParameter1;
    var param2 = pMoreParams.pParameter2;
}
```

**SIDE NOTE**

You are sending in SQL for the the server to execute. I know it is convinient, but this is a HUGE security issue that will lead to [SQL Injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A1-Injection) that will allow an attacker to control your SQL server.

Comment: Is the only way to define all the parameter names I might use in advance in a class? I find it odd that I am so close in being able to loop the pMoreParams x times but not read what is in there without first defining what might be in there?

Comment: @Andrew Agreed with Andres Nava about the side note -- that's a really dangerous thing to do.

Comment: Yes I wasn't too keen with retrieving, modifying and sending SQL but it was a start while the product is still in development, but now with my new found parameterisation technique I figured out in my answer below I should now be able to do things much more securely.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after a good sleep, I think I have come up with a solution which meets my requirements to not have to define all my possible and future parameters in a class and also satisfies some of the SQL injection concerns, having read up on using parameterisation;

Here's the data I JSON.stringify and pass via AJAX to the controller;

```
var chart01Params = {
pSQLCon: "ConnectionString",
pSQL: "MySQLFile.sql", // accessible only by the server from MapPath
pMoreParams : 
    [
        {
            "name" : "pParameterXYZ",
            "value": "12345ABC"
        },
    ],
};
```

...which looks like this in POST request body;

```
{"pSQLCon":"ConnectionString","pSQL":"MySQLFile.sql","pMoreParams":[{"name":"pParameterXYZ","value":"12345ABC"}]}
```

Here's my class;

```
public class SQLParam
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my controller head;

```
public string GETMYJSON(string pSQLCon, string pSQL, List<SQLParam> pMoreParams)
```

...before my controller executes the SQL command it will add any parameters and values to the SQL query, which I hope will make it more secure from SQL Injection attack;

```
foreach (SQLParam parameter in pMoreParams)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter.name, SqlDbType.Char);
    cmd.Parameters[parameter.name].Value = parameter.value;
}
```

And it works great!  If I want to send up parameters that a query expects, I can do so without having to include them in a class and I can also, still, use local client-side scripting to take choices/input from the DOM and set parameter values as long as I know the Index in the object of the parameter value I want to change.